# Vue.js 2 bind a class in a variable

Tags: javascript, laravel, data-binding, vuejs2

I`m using the Vue.js 2 and Laravel 5.3 to build a web.

When I click the `ajaxbtn`, the class do not bind in the variable, Any idea?

*Here is the html.

```
<div  id="root" class="container">
   <ajaxbtns>
      <ajaxbtn name="get taiwanstay"  url="api/taiwanstay" :selected="true" ></ajaxbtn>
       <ajaxbtn name="get itwyp" url="api/itwyp" ></ajaxbtn>
    </ajaxbtns>
 </div>
```

*Here is the script

```
Vue.component('ajaxbtns',{
    template: 
    `
        <div class="tabs">
          <ul>
            <slot></slot>
          </ul>
        </div>
    `,
    data : function () {
        return {
            allAjaxBtn : []
        };
    },
    created: function () {
        this.allAjaxBtn = this.$children;
    }
});

Vue.component('ajaxbtn',{
    template: 
    `
        <li :class="{ 'is-active' : btnActive }">
            <a @click="ajaxbtnClick(name)" href="#" >@{{ name }}</a>
        </li>
    `,
    props : {
        name: { required: true },
        url : { required: true },
        selected: { default : false }
    },
    data :function () {
        return {
            btnActive : false
        }
    },
    created: function () {
        this.btnActive = this.selected;
    },
    methods : {
        ajaxbtnClick : function (name) {
            this.$parent.allAjaxBtn.forEach( btn => {
                this.btnActive = (btn.name == name);
            });
        }    
    }
});


 new Vue({
    el: '#root'
});
```

Comment: Does the variable btnActive changes?

Comment: yes, it change.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the binding of the variable, that works fine. The problem is that `btnActive` will change for each iteration. You may get lucky in the case that the last btn matches, which would set it to true. However, if the condition was met earlier, it would be switched from true to false anyway.

Instead, conditionalize your query and then assign the `btn` to the `btnActive`:

```
if (btn.name == name) {
    this.btnActive = btn;
}
```

Comment: Using this code, when I click the second ` ajaxbtn`, the first one would not remove the class, and  on `ajaxbtn` template `<li :class="{ 'is-active' : btnActive }">` btnActive should be boolen, why using the `btn` object to setting it?